# Download a file with Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, download

In my project there is the possibility to upload a file; I developed this reading the [Symfony2 documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/file_uploads.html).

I didn't fine instruction to create an action in the controller able to download those files.

How could I do?

Answer (score 1):

My Version looks like this:

```
/**
 * @Route("/download/{file_id}", name="download_file")
 */
public function downloadAction($file_id)
{
    // get your filepath from db somehow by file_id or whatever
    $path = ...

    $file = getimagesize($path);

    $response = new Response();
    $response->setContent(file_get_contents($path));
    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', $file['mime']);
    $response->headers->set('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="' . $filename . '"');

    return $response;
}
```

Comment: In my project, the uploadDir depends from the file. To define the path, i have to call the method getUploadDir() inside of my object. But the method is protected. Is it sure to make it public? Or, otherwise, how could I do?

Answer (score 0):

```
$response=new Response();
$response->setContent(file_get_contents($localFilePath));
```

For forcefully download you may use this:

```
$file_url = 'http://www.myremoteserver.com/file.exe';
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary"); 
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . basename($file_url) . "\""); 
readfile($file_url); // do the double-download-dance (dirty but worky)
```

Comment: In my project, the uploadDir depends from the file. To define the path, i have to call the method getUploadDir() inside of my object. But the method is protected. Is it sure to make it public? Or, otherwise, how could I do?